# Selecting a cell shows a button and deselecting hides the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I want a button to show when i select a cell, when i select the same cell or another cell i want the button to hide. So one button should only be visible at a time.

What i have:

**in my .h file:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *isselectednow;
```

**and my .m file:**

*Viewdidload:*

```
self.isselectednow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:1];
```

*cellForRowAtIndexPath:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }


 //[cell addSubview:[self drawSeparationView:(indexPath.row)]];

 UILabel *DateName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100100];
 DateName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 //DateName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row ];
 DateName.text = objects[indexPath.row];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonOnCellPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Update" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(DEVICE_SIZE.width - 60, 18, 55, 15);

[cell addSubview:button];
if ([indexPath compare:self.isselectednow] == NSOrderedSame) {
    button.hidden = NO;
}
else{
    button.hidden = YES;
}

 UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100101];
 lbl1.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100102];
 lbl2.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100103];
 lbl3.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 UILabel *lbl4 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100104];
 lbl4.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 UILabel *lbl5 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100105];
 lbl5.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);

 UITextField *breakfastName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100200];
 breakfastName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
  initWithString:@"Name here"
  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 breakfastName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 [breakfastName setDelegate:self];
 //[breakfastName addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

 UITextField *OutName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100201];
 OutName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
  initWithString:@"Name here"
  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 OutName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 [OutName setDelegate:self];

 UITextField *lunchName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100202];
 lunchName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
  initWithString:@"Name here"
  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 lunchName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 [lunchName setDelegate:self];

 UITextField *InName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100203];
 InName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
  initWithString:@"Name here"
  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 InName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 [InName setDelegate:self];

 UITextField *eveningName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100204];
 eveningName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
  initWithString:@"Name here"
  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 eveningName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);
 [eveningName setDelegate:self];

 UITextField *othersName = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:100205];
 othersName.attributedPlaceholder =
 [[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:@"Name here"
 attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColorFromRGB(0x141414)}];
 othersName.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x141414);



 cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 cell.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xf3f0e9);
```

return cell;
 }

*didSelectRowAtIndexPath:*

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
if ([indexPath compare:self.isselectednow] == NSOrderedSame) {
    self.isselectednow = nil;
}
else{
    self.isselectednow = indexPath;
}

[tableView endUpdates];
//[tableView reloadData];
```

[image]

Comment: And could you post your entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @LyndseyScott The problem is that when i select a cell and then deselect the same cell or select another cell the first cell's button isn't hidden. It stays show when i select it the first time. I've also updated my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs about `beginUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates):

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously.

Although you've changed the `isSelectedNow` boolean, you haven't actually specified any insertion, deletion, or selection operations between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. So you're not actually beginning or ending any updates to the cells' content with that code.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but taking out `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView beginUpdates];` and reinserting `[tableView reloadData];` would result in a proper data reload.

Edit:

Aside from that, the problem is that you're reusing your cells with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, but you're adding a new `UIButton` subview each time, so you're basically putting each new `UIButton` over the old. I suggest doing what you've done for all your labels and textfields in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -- reuse your update button by adding it to your custom table view cell and accessing it with `viewWithTag:`.

Comment: Even when i delete the `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` and insert `[tableView reloadData]` it doesn't work. What happens now is, when i select a cell, the button appears (as it should), but when i select the same cell again, the button doesn't gets hidden. So there should only be one `update` button visible at the same time. I've attached a picture of my tableview.

Comment: @Dridia That's why I asked you to post the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method (didn't realize you'd updated it until now). You're reusing your cells, but you're adding a new UIButton subview each time. I've updated my answer to include a more thorough explanation.

Comment: I manage to make it work thanks to you! I appreciate it a lot!